# What is the difference between developing apps for Android Automotive OS and Android Auto?

Tags: android-automotive

Google released developer documentation for Android Auto in 2014 and Android Automotive OS in 2019. What is the difference?

Android Auto: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2014/11/begin-developing-with-android-auto.html

Android Automotive OS: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/05/developing-apps-for-android-automotive.html

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**: *Android Automotive OS runs natively in the car, while Android Auto runs on the phone and can be projected to the car over USB or Wi-Fi.*

**Android Auto**

- **Runtime**: Runs on the phone, displays on the phone or projected by the
  phone to the car
- **App architecture**: App developer extends mobile app, all user setup
  happens in the mobile app
- **UI**: Google's Android Auto app draws every UI pixel, everything is
  optimized for driving

**Android Automotive OS**

- **Runtime**: Android OS runs on the car, phone is not required
- **App architecture**: Developer deploys an APK specifically for the car,
  all user setup happens in the car (parked UI)
- **UI**: Google, the OEM, and the app developer draw UI, some screens are
  optimized for driving

  - Developers create the setup / login / settings UI for the car (parked
    UI)
  - Google publishes source code for an AOSP media UI (OEM takes
    responsibility of driver safety, not Google)
  - OEMs make adjustments to the media UI to fit their screens (driving
    UI)